# Truncate float to multiple of 10

Tags: python

I have the number 67.14, for example.

I need to set another variable as the next multiple of 10 down (60, in this case).

Would it be possible to just get the "7.14" from "67.14" and take it away?

Comment: `float(str(num)[1:])`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`//`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) to get the floored quotient of x and y:

```
67.14 // 10 * 10
```

Result:

```
60.0
```

Use `%` to get the remainder of x / y:

```
67.14 % 10
```

Result:

```
7.140000000000001
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier solution:

- divide by 10
- round to integer
- multiply by 10

  ```
  >> int(11.7/10)*10
  10
  ```

Comment: Instead of `int(11.7/10)`, you can use `11.7//10`.

Answer (score 0):

Type:

```
n = 67.14
print n - n % 10

>> result is 60.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%` (modulo) sign should help you here:

`new = old - (old % 10)`